# How to count sent messages after specific day in SQL(Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting

I received a report recently about the `count` number of SMS messages that sent to the user number after the day of the  un-subscription from a service ,**I need to check this report is true or not by using the original table**,below is my tables where `table a` is the report and `table b` is the original table.

I need to **count the number of messages that sent after the UN-subscription date** from the service and classify it by using `STATUS_CODE` `Delivered` and `OTB.Delivered` messages.

to make it understandable  I put the expected result for these numbers as an example `(9537603785678,9537123485905)`, **each number have only one un-subscription date.**

[image]

Comment: Table b is original table. From where to find unsubscription date then?

Comment: @Tejash my report doesn't require me to find the `un-subscription date` , I will take the un-subscription date from `Table A` and look for the messages that sent after the `un-subscription date` in `table A` for each mobile number in `table B` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use group by as following:

```
select b.A_NUMBER, b.DEST_NUMBER, b.status_code, 
       count(distinct b.rowid) as msgs_count_after_unsub_date
From b join a
On (a.a_number = b.a_number
And a.dest_number = b.dest_number
And b.date >= a.unsubscription_date)
Group by b.A_NUMBER, b.DEST_NUMBER, b.status_code;
```

OR

```
select b.A_NUMBER, b.DEST_NUMBER, b.status_code, 
       count(1) as msgs_count_after_unsub_date
From b where b.date
>= (select min(a.unsubscription_date)
From a where
a.a_number = b.a_number
And a.dest_number = b.dest_number)
Group by b.A_NUMBER, b.DEST_NUMBER, b.status_code;
```

Cheers!!